# PHP something wrong with while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so now its display results like 3 times in a row

```
$user_apps = mysql_query("SELECT a.name,a.download_url FROM user_apps as ua LEFT JOIN 
apps as a ON  (ua.app_id=a.app_id)  
WHERE ua.user_id='$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
while($raw = mysql_fetch_array($user_apps)){
    $name = $raw['name'];
    $url = $raw['download_url'];
    echo $name;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $url;
}
```

Database Table Structure(since I am new to the site and did not know how to display the table structure  I just exported the sql)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_apps` (
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`app_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apps` (
 `app_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `description` text NOT NULL,
 `icon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `download_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `default` int(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

I'v tried different Join types but that does not seem to work.

Comment: you are overwriting `$app_id` on each loop. you need to put your 2nd query inside your 1st loop. Or just learn how to do a `JOIN` query, and prevent doing a loop in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the join query for get the result check bellow example query

```
$user_apps = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT a.name,a.download_url FROM user_apps as ua LEFT JOIN apps as a ON (ua.app_id=a.app_id)  WHERE ua.user_id='$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
while($raw = mysql_fetch_array($user_apps)){
$name = $raw['name'];
$url = $raw['download_url'];
echo $name;
echo $url;
}
```

**change the join type as per your requirement. the above query for only example**

- INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH
  tables
- LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows
  from the right table
- RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched
  rows from the left table
- FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

**more about join [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)** 
**AND also check this http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/**

Comment: Here is what it says:

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '==a.app_id) WHERE ua.user_id='7'' at line 1

Comment: thanks it display the results now BUT its like duplicating the results for some reason.

Comment: it's depend on the join type. read more about join type and used join type as per your requirement

Comment: so I took a look a the link you provided about Join and tried the different joins but none of them seemed to take away the duplicate results

Comment: @user2971050 update your question with table structures and some  data

Comment: @user2971050 not change the original  question that is not good. only  update at bottom of question some more information. provide your database table structure with data of both table so i can help

Comment: Sorry I am new to the site where is the update question button at?

Comment: in bottom of your question three link (share|edit|flag ) click edit to edit your question

Comment: NVM I got it to work by adding SELECT DISTINCT at the beginning of the query, thanks for the help you really save me!

Answer (score 0):

You have used single quotes in query at `user_id`='$user_id' .
Are you sure your user_id is char, varchar or text? Just print_r($user_apps) and check it has any records or not? If user_id is int,tinyin than remove single quote.